# How to find values entered or not in any of the textboxes using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having three with ID's **ppl1**, **pp2** and **ppl3**.

I can find whether there is any values entered in these textbox by making some javascript functions like given below

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$("#ppl1").change(function () {
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ppl2").change(function () {
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ppl3").change(function () {
```

Now I need to check if any of the text box has been entered. That is to use some **logical OR** (**||**) in the above functions.

Hope this can be done simple, but I couldn't get exact thing even after prolonged googling.

Comment: `$("#ppl1, #ppl2, #ppl3").change(function () {..})`

Comment: `$("[id^='ppl']").filter(function(i,elm){ return elm.val().trim().length > 0 }).length >= 1` will tell you whether one or more text box has been entered or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(function(){ // This is equal to "$(document).ready(function () {" 
    // $("[id^='ppl']") This selector works as well. 
    $("#ppl1, #ppl2, #ppl3").on('change',function(e){
        if ($(this).val().trim().length > 0)
        {
            // The input has changed, and there is something in it. 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @JooNice great, then mark it as your answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Bind keyup event on the input
$('input:text').keyup(function() {

  // If value is not empty
  if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
    console.log("input with ID: " + $(this).attr('id') + " has value")

  } else {
    console.log("input with ID: " + $(this).attr('id') + " has no value")
  }
}).keyup(); // Trigger the keyup event, thus running the handler on page load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="ppl1" id="ppl1" />
<input name="ppl2" id="ppl2" value='123' />
<input name="ppl3" id="ppl3" />
```

You can use `.keyup()`